# How to keep changes made to a class when the page refreshes with Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a table of data for the user to look through and make changes. They have the option to delete a row if they want. When they delete a row it sends back to the db what row is to be deleted. For the user the row won't delete right away but it will get a new class 'deleted' that has some styles to let the user know it's being deleted. I also have the page refreshing every 10 minutes and when it refreshes the new added 'deleted' class goes away.

How can I get it that the class will stay on the row when the page refreshes?

Here is the timer function for the timer to know when to refresh the page. I'm using ajax to refresh the page.

```
        function startClock() {
          // Get the time to stop the effect
          var stopTime = new Date();
          stopTime.setMinutes(stopTime.getMinutes() + 10);
          // Get a reference to the timer so it can be cancelled later
          timer = setInterval(function () {
              // Check to see if the timer should stop
              var currentTime = new Date();
              if (currentTime < stopTime) {
                  triggerDataTable(); //refresh dataTable
                  var randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
              } else {
                  // Stop the timer
                  clearInterval(timer);
              }
          }, 600000);
      }
```

Would I use localStorage? If so how would I actually do it? I'm not familiar with storing local values or anything like that.

Comment: Maybe instead of actually deleting the row from the database, you could actually give the row a column with a status type (active, deleted etc.). That way when refreshing the page you can just change the class based on the status of the row.

Comment: @Bram I give the row a class of 'deleted'.. but how do I keep that class when the page refreshes?

Comment: instead of deleting the row from the database you update the row instead, giving it a status (archived for example) to indicate it's deleted. That way the deleted rows are still in your database. On refresh you load all your rows, rows with a different status get a different class.

Comment: If the row is being deleted or "archived" in the database, why is the server still sending the row to the client when the page is refreshed? When the page is refreshed, I assume it will re-query the server for which rows to display - but the server should not send the deleted items to the client.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% sure about this but what about doing something like this:

```
var deletedRow = $(".deleted");
localStorage.setItem( deletedRow, $(".deleted").val() );
```

Answer (score 2):

try using sessionstorage over localstorage

Session Storage property maintains a separate storage area for each given origin and for a session .

Local Storage does the same thing, but persists even when the browser is closed and reopened.

```
sessionStorage.setItem('item', value);
sessionStorage.getItem('item');
```

Comment: would 'item' be the class of the row that's being changed?

Comment: item can be any key(String). value can be a any thing(string, numeric, object, array). So its upto you to according to your requirement.

Comment: So something like this: var deletedRow = $(".deleted");    sessionStorage.setItem( deletedRow, $(".deleted").val() );
   sessionStorage.getItem( deletedRow );

Comment: do I need to put the sessionStorage in a function or can it just be anywhere within the javascript

Comment: you can use it anywhere. 
it works like this
window.sessionStorage.setItem('item', value);
var value = window.sessionStorage.getItem('item');

Comment: item would be the row class that has changed, such as $(".deleted")  ?.. I tried following your example and when the page refreshes the new 'deleted' class goes away

Comment: You can do the following
when you add the class 'deleted' to a row say at index 'i'
store the following
window.sessionStorage.setItem('index', i);
now on reload
you can do this
if(window.sessionStorage.getItem('index')){
    // add class deleted to row at index
}

Comment: I can't seem to get it to work. I'll have to keep trying some stuff